# Can't access all profiles

Tags: bug, status-completed, ios-app

- App Version: 1.4.5
- Device: iPad 4 (Wi-Fi)
- OS Version: Version 9.3.1 (Build 13E238)
  Wanted to find a question I had asked on Apple.SE without scrolling down hunting for it.  Clicked the avatar but got only the "Travel" profile—only things in Travel.SE.  Selected Apple again and repeated.  Still got Travel.

Comment: How many rep you see for your Travel profile using the iOS app? Maybe you registered a different account in the app by mistake, when signing in.

Comment: No, it's the same. I have only ever used one e-mail address on any SE site.  Rep is the same, and the list of questions is the same.

Answer (score 2):

This will be fixed in 1.5.0.2.

Right now the menu icon always takes you to your highest rep site.  It's a vestige of the fact that on the iPhone it takes you to a network profile rather than a site profile.

There are currently two ways to get to your profile on Apple.SE.

1. Go to your profile from the menu.  In the bottom right, you'll see a list of your other sites.  You can tap "Ask Different" to get to your Apple.SE profile.
2. While Apple.SE is open, tap the last menu item for the site, the one with three dots.  In the resulting screen, you'll see an item for your site profile.

In the next release, tapping on your menu icon while in a site will open up the profile for that site.

You can try this change when it's built by [becoming a beta tester](https://docs.google.com/a/stackoverflow.com/forms/d/18ZDfsBm35cV72Gzf88zPaMLQwrSRPwP2__RnPb-uqTs/viewform).